# What is the justification for the running time of this loop?

Tags: algorithms, complexity, runtime

I don't understand why the running time of the following loop is n+2 ? Also why the running time of the statements inside the loop is n+1 ?

```
Double test(int n){  
      int sum=0;  -> 1 time
      int i;  -> 0 time
      for(i=0; i<=n;i++)  -> n+2 times
      {
        scanf("%d",&a);  -> n+1 times
        sum=sum+a;  -> n+1 times
      }
      return sum;  -> 1 time
    }
```

Comment: Use paper & pencil and walk through this by hand for n = 3.  You'll probably see the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of loop you've written is entered `n+1` times (`i` from `0` to `n`), after that the variable `i` is incremented again, it's value now becomes `n+1`. Then it is compared to `n` ( `i <= n` ), this test fails and the body of the loop is skipped.